# Merge PHP and HTML Code

Tags: php, html

I run a Joomla site and one of the components I use is written in PHP. I need to change the behaviour of a button in the component.

The code for the button is:

```
<a href="/<?php echo DiscussHelper::getRegistrationLink();?>" class="btn btn-success mt-10"><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_EASYDISCUSS_REGISTER_HERE' );?></a>
```

I need to call the following HTML code on click of the above button:

`<a href="#" class="pwebbox403_toggler">Create an account</a>`

I am unclear as to how to merge these 2 snippets. Any help will really be appreciated.

Just one quick point. The button already has the "Create and account" caption and hence the caption can be omitted from the HTML code snippet.

Thanks and regards,
Mangesh

Comment: you want to call this class `pwebbox403_toggler`?

Comment: yes, absolutely right

Comment: add it to the class of the first link, like this `class="btn btn-success mt-10 pwebbox403_toggler"`

Comment: Works. Thanks a ton :) Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it to the class of the first link,

like this `class="btn btn-success mt-10 pwebbox403_toggler"`